# Android application is stuck on links in Android Webview

Tags: android, web-applications, authentication, android-webview, quora

**Background**

I am making an app which uses Quora links All Links(profiles,answers,topics,except sign in) are Opening in My App only .

**Problem**

- There is a option "Open in App" , I want to Remove that
  Option.Clicking on the Cross Button Doesn't work.
- User Can't Sign in the Quora , Sign in Link is not opening.

In both cases the app is stuck .I tried WebView Client Solution that is 
working fine but for sign in case it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two require that you need:

- Hide element of website (here is "Open in App" button)
- Disable event of element in website (here is signin click)

and solution you can found at WebViewClient class:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(!url.equals(currentUrl)){ //currentUrl is url that signin with navigated.
            view.loadUrl(url);  
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // hide element by class name
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        // hide element by id
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('your_id')[0].style.display='none';})()");

    }
});
```

Comment: how to find the className ? i mean that element doesn't appear in browser so how can i inspect to find out the class name

Comment: the url that you load, you can open it in brower or get html code from webview.